# fsutil can't query quota usage?

Tags: ntfs, windows-sbs-2003, quota

This is a followup question from [Disk quota problem in Windows Server SBS 2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/92791/disk-quota-problem-in-windows-server-sbs-2003), which has not yet been resolved.

When I run quota query (`fsutil quota query e:`) under the administrator account, I get an error saying *"Error:  Access is denied."*

Apparently I can't access the NTFS-quota information from the E: drive of the Windows SBS 2003 server. Is this problem related to USN journal? I checked C: has USN journal while E: doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to delete the partition in Windows Disk Management, and again create a NTFS partition. After that quota work fine.

Comment: Yeah, formatting that partition will solve the problem. But is there anyway to fix it without a reformat?